# Canvas painting time issue with getImageData() in game loop

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, memory, cpu

I'm working on a small video game which includes a drawing loop and I experienced a strange behavior with MS Edge (but it happens in an other way on Chrome too).

At one particular time, I want to get data about pixels and use, **just one time**, `ctx.getImageData()`
It triggers a CPU memory increase at this very precise moment (I know this function is costly)... But during all next iterations of the loop, the painting time dramatically increase.

Here is the link: http://millgraphik.alwaysdata.net/cpu-test/

And the code: http://millgraphik.alwaysdata.net/cpu-test/js/canvas.js

You can test with MS Edge, launch the performance record just after page load. The getImageData is triggered at about 3 seconds after page load. Here is the result of performance test:

[image: in green, the painting duration]

*in green, the painting duration*

So what could be the reason of this increasing painting time?

Comment: I have seen your problem but it's hard to reason. Now you should preferably do some experiments. I would first try delaying the loop itereation for like 200ms at the turn you call  `ctx.getImageData()` to see how paints change.

Comment: I tried lot of things, including delaying...  :(

Answer (score 2):

Chrome and Edge are nowadays both based on Chromium, which uses GPU to accelerate 2D canvas operations. If you navigate to `edge://flags` or `chrome://flags` (on Chrome) and disable *Accelerated 2D canvas*, you'll notice that the slow behavior starts instantly instead of after the `getImageData()` call. This is because the canvas is now, by default, being rendered by your CPU.

But why does it start off fast and then slow down after `getImageData()`? When using GPU acceleration, it appears Chrome at least swaps to the CPU based renderer after using `getImageData()`.

Here's a quote from a related [Chromium bug ticket comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=775549#c11):

> ...
>
> The problem in Chrome is that every single call to getImageData is
> generating a readback from the GPU, which is a slow operation.  We
> have a performance heuristic that switches canvases to software
> rendering mode (no GPU) when getImageData is use a lot. The problem is
> that the heuristic looks for cases where getImageData is used in three
> consecutive animation frames.  We need to change that rule so that it
> will catch cases like this.

So your code is triggering whatever heuristic Chromium is currently using to detect frequent `getImageData()` calls.

[Another related comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1239467):

> We moved to use gpu to do all canvas related operation few years ago.
> One issue we have is that GPU is significant slower than CPU to run
> getImageData, but GPU is faster than CPU for all other canvas
> operations. So we made a decision, the first getImageData call runs on
> GPU and all subsequent call to getImageData runs on CPU. This is
> because we believe the users may do more getImageData calls, and we
> want to be fast to handle those.
>
> Software Rendering(CPU) result is slightly different than GPU
> rendering result, that is the difference you have observed in the two
> getImageData calls.
>
> The flag you found, it allows you to specify if getImageData will be
> used frequently. If it does, use CPU; otherwise, use GPU (meaning
> calling getImageData will not cause the change of renderer). So
> clearly, this would fix the issue!
>
> We are not ready to release this feature yet -- still at testing
> stage. We plan to launch it in M94-95. This issue will be gone by that
> time.
>
> Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks ! It's a high advanced issue... I've experienced exactly the same switch cpu/gpu on chrome after just one call to getImageData. 
So now the question is : How to force canvas to go back to the GPU engine ? Can we ? or do I leave this function ?

Comment: Maybe using a second canvas to get the result of getimagedata()... I'll try to see if it's not worse. Any advices are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

I've created an offscreen canvas with CSS `display: none;`   and get my pixels datas with `getImageData()` in this offscreen canvas.
It seems to maintain the painting with GPU.

Here is the new test : http://millgraphik.alwaysdata.net/cpu-test2/

and the code http://millgraphik.alwaysdata.net/cpu-test2/js/canvas.js

**EDIT : A better solution with a fragment canvas : http://millgraphik.alwaysdata.net/cpu-test3/js/canvas.js**

and the perf test on Edge (similar on chrome) :

[image]

What do you think of this new way ?

Comment: That's good to know. Perhaps you can also use canvas under a document fragment too.

Comment: The fragment solution is working fine. I suppose that it's a more efficient way...
 Here is the new code : http://millgraphik.alwaysdata.net/cpu-test3/js/canvas.js
Any comments on this solution are welcome

Comment: That's great. Now i would try `frag.append(ctx.cloneNode(true))` and do **all** operations on cloned ctx which is under the `frag`. Once done, just do `ctx.replaceWith(frag)` through rAF. Now frag becomes empty again and in next rAF cycle clone `ctx` under it again and proceed likewise. How about that? Like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bzrL6dpu/5)

Comment: What could be the benefit ? The offscreen <canvas> is just for an operation that switch the canvas from GPU to CPU. But ok I will try !

Comment: I am just trying to split the concerns into two like processing and display. Let's make all operations offline and use the live DOM just for display under rAF. A further step could be defining your context canvas as a custom element and doing all your calculations under shadow DOM perhaps. Can't tell but JS engines might have developed some GPU or multicore CPU processing for such cases. Just experiments nothing more.